# Inconsistency between the reputation in the achievement drop down and profile's reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, android-app

I was just browsing my profile when I noticed that in the achievement's drop down its showing +28 reputation for today(and missing an entry) but in the reputation's tab of my profile its showing +30 reputation.

Today I have received +30 rep(at the time of writing this post).

Here is a screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

I also quickly checked on the Stack Exchange app on android and found the same inconsistency.

Below is the screenshot of the mobile app

[image]

So I am wondering why is that, is it a bug?

**Update 1**

Just to make sure that its not a caching issue just tried after some time and still feels like that the issue persists.

Here is an updated screen shot
[image]

Comment: Probably just caching.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: ya maybe, so I just quickly cleared my browser's cache and found no change, and then it can't be cached both in the browser and mobile app at the same time, unless if its a server side caching issue.

Comment: I meant server side caching. Give it a little time - a few hours. If it hasn't caught up in a day, then it's probably a bug.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I checked(and also updated the post) and found that the inconsistency still persists.May be this is a bug.

Comment: @Shiva Having same scenario in my profile both for SO Site and Android App. Was this a bug or just caching issue?

Comment: @UmairKhan: It was a long time back but I feel it was a bug, or update issue on the site. We never fixed it, and frankly I too never followed it back on it